# how to return a mysql select as an array of arrays in json using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to export a mysql request (select) to a json array of array, so that `JSON.parse` in javascript will return an array of arrays and not an array of objects as what will happen following answers to similar questions [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383664/1174052).

What should be changed to translate a mysql request into a json array of array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For `json_encode` to return a JSON array of array you need a numerically indexed array.

This can be obtained with the following, generic function:

```
    function SqlSelectToJsonTable($result,$withNames=false){
        // result a mysqli::query object, 
        // withNames: boolean, should the column names be returned as first row
        $return_arr = array();
        echo $result->num_rows;
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
            if($withNames == true){
                $return_arr[0] = array();
                $fields = $result->fetch_fields();
                foreach ($fields as $field){
                    echo "column: ".$field->name." ";
                    array_push($return_arr[0],$field->name);
                }
            }
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $return_arr[]= array_values($row);
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        return json_encode($return_arr);
    }
```

Used as in the following:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, title FROM Posts";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $jsonTable = SqlSelectToJsonTable($result);
    echo '<br/>'.$jsonTable;

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var jsTable = JSON.parse('".$jsonTable."');
        </script>";

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Where jsTable will effectively be an array of arrays. Note the option `withNames` allowing to add the column names as the first row, usefull if you try to [pass this array to javascript for google visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176990/1174052).